# How can I remove the rows of my dataset using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, mask

Here's the dataset I'm dealing with (called `depo_dataset`):

[image]
Some entries starting from the second column (0.0) might be 0.000..., the goal is for each column starting from the 2nd one, I will generate a separate array of `Energy`, with the 0.0... entry in the column and associated `Energy` removed. I'm trying to use a `mask` in pandas. Here's what I tried:

```
for column in depo_dataset.columns[1:]:  
    e = depo_dataset['Energy'].copy()
    mask = depo_dataset[column] == 0
```

Then I don't know how can I drop the 0 entry (assume there is one), and the corresponding element is `e`?

For instance, suppose we have `depo_dataset['0.0']` to be `0.4, 0.0, 0.4, 0.1`, and `depo_dataset['Energy']` is `0.82, 0.85, 0.87, 0.90`, I hope to drop the `0.0` entry in `depo_dataset['0.0']`, and `0.85` in `depo_dataset['Energy']` .

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. Could you add your expected output?

Comment: @Bushmaster Thanks for the comment! Just added an expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just us .loc on the DataFrame to filter out some rows.
Here a little example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Energy': [0.82, 0.85, 0.87, 0.90], 
   0.0: [0.4, 0.0, 0.4, 0.1], 
   0.1: [0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1]
})
```

[image]

```
energies = {}
for column in df.columns[1:]:
   energies[column] = df.loc[df[column] != 0, ['Energy', column]]

energies[0.0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! `energies` here is a new dataframe, is that right?

Comment: Sorry, this line was missing. It is in my example a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.loc`:

```py
depo_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Energy':[0.82, 0.85, 0.87, 0.90],
                             '0.0':[0.4, 0.0, 0.4, 0.1],
                             '0.1':[1,2,3,4]})

dataset_no_zeroes = depo_dataset.loc[(depo_dataset.iloc[:,1:] !=0).all(axis=1),:]
```

Explanation:

```
(depo_dataset.iloc[:,1:] !=0)
```

makes a dataframe from all cols beginning with the second one with bool values indicating if the cell is zero.

```
.all(axis=1)
```

take the rows of the dataframe '(axis =1)' and only return true if all values of the  row are true